# How to convert the phpmyadmin latin1_swedish_ci password into original text form

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hi everyone I am creating a website but unfortunately I forget the password and that password is encoded into latin1_swedish_ci

So can anyone please guide me on how I can get the original password?

$2y$10$.FUiqi1YNqPBTxstbratouNEux7TsPPZ8/YOrV.Bd2JbVFD95G1nS

this is an encoded password

Comment: It's not encoded, it's hashed. Hashes are not reversible. If you want to check if a password matches the hash use [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify)`.